# Getting error in round method in python (AttributeError: module 'math' has no attribute 'round')

Tags: python

Here is my program and i am getting "(AttributeError: module 'math' has no attribute 'round')" error message

```
import math
def profit(info):
  cost = info['cost_price']
  sell =info['sell_price']
  num = info['inventory']

  return math.round((sell-cost)*num)
```

Comment: If you check [the official documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#module-math) you can see the error message is correct. It is a [built-in function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#round) in Python.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Unlike ceil, floor, and trunc, round can be found in the standard library as a built-in function.

So you don't need import "math"

```
def profit(info):
  cost = info['cost_price']
  sell =info['sell_price']
  num = info['inventory']

 return round((sell-cost)*num)
```